# where can I find the list of systemd node exporter metrics?

Tags: systemd, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have looked and googled all around , unable to find the list of systemd metrics that node exporter exposes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

List of node_systemd metrics:

```
node_systemd_unit_state - Systemd unit
node_systemd_unit_start_time_seconds - Start time of the unit since unix epoch in seconds
node_systemd_system_running - Whether the system is operational (see 'systemctl is-system-running')
node_systemd_units - Summary of systemd unit states
node_systemd_service_restart_total - Service unit count of Restart triggers
node_systemd_timer_last_trigger_seconds - Seconds since epoch of last trigger
node_systemd_socket_accepted_connections_total - Total number of accepted socket connections
node_systemd_socket_current_connections - Current number of socket connections
node_systemd_socket_refused_connections_total - Total number of refused socket connections
```

Keep in mind that the systemd collector is disabled by default. You can enable it by passing `--collector.systemd` when starting node-exporter.

P.S. At the moment I do not have access to a prometheus / node-exporter instance but I got the list above by having a quick glance at the code for that collector [here](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/collector/systemd_linux.go#L56).

If you have access to a running node-exporter and the collector in question is enabled, you can easily find all metrics by going to /metrics on whichever port node-exporter is exposed on.

Answer (score 7):

The collection of systemd metrics is [disabled by default](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#disabled-by-default). To enable it you need to start the NodeExporter with the following flag:

```
./node_exporter --collector.systemd
```

Once you do that the systemd metrics will be shown in the node exporter `/metrics` url with the prefix `node_systemd`.